# DirectX Device Options

Tags: c++, menu, directx, device

Almost all games today have a video options menu where you can choose the quality of textures, shaders, shadows, resolution etc. I'm just wondering how I could find the available options? (like if the user has a 1080x1050 screen, there shouldn't be an option for 1920x1200 resolution)

If that's not how it works, do I have to build a list of features and just allow the user choose choose any of them? How would I do that? I'm using C++ by the way.

Comment: You generally provide options based on configurations you have tested depending on your target distribution. The minimum hardware you support usually defines the low end settings up to the highest settings which usually take advantage of the latest hardware available. That said for learning purposes or if you aren't working on a game studio shipping titles I wouldn't bother with this support initially until you have a game.

Comment: So you are saying I shouldn't implement optimization options?

Comment: I'm saying it may be a bit premature. I'm assuming you're writing a game engine from scratch. I believe in my first DirectX game I simply hard coded resolution to 800x600 so I could get on with the important parts.

Comment: You're probably right. I just want to sketch up the basic framework. I want to create a placeholder so that it would be easier to add this functionality later. But I guess I should create a working prototype before I try to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you won't be doing any of this for a while, but if/when you do, there is no magic wand, you have to have to deal with all the options individually and it depends on the features you support.

For example, with textures, the "low" option could mean that you don't load the highest mip and instead start with the second highest.

You can do something similar with the LODs of your models.

A lot of the options are versions of your shaders.  So you can write one shaded that supports four dynamic lights, another version that supports one and a third version that doesn't support any.  Then you have other options, like the number of texture passes and shadow generation techniques.  This leads to a combinatorial explosion of shader versions.  So most games will have a way of stitching chunks of shader code together to form the combination of options they want for each model and the quality settings.

The screen resolution options are the most straight-forward.  Depending on which version of DirectX you are using, there are different functions you can call to enumerate the fullscreen modes that are supported by the device.  For example [EnumAdapterModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174314.aspx) on DirectX 9 and [EnumAdapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174538.aspx) on DirectX 10.